Is there an example of a non-compact Kahler manifold with a Ricci-flat line bundle that is not torsion?
As well-known, for a compact Kahler manifold $M$,  **$c_1(K_M)=0$ (**which is equivalent to $K_M$ being Ricci-flat, by Griffiths-Harris book page 148) as integral class is equivalent to some positive power of of $K_M$ being trivial.  I guess this fact is also true for general holomorphic line bundles. So it is natural to ask the following condition.

Question: Is there  an example of a non-compact Kahler manifold with
a Ricci-flat line bundle $L$ that is not torsion (torsion bundle means that, there exists some
positive integer $n$ satisfying $nL=\mathcal{O}_M$)?

